# Net use with netbios format causes account lockout - with FQDN format does not

Tags: windows, domain

I have two domains with no trust - DNS is being forwarded for name resolution and the DNS Zone of one is delegated , but otherwise the domains have no relationship
I am having a problem with running the command

```
net use \\SERVER2  /user:DOM2\User2
```

on a member servers of DOM1 as the user DOM1\User1.  Whilst it has the the same password as User2 - User2 gets locked out.  However running

```
net use \\SERVER2  /user:User2@DOM2.DOM1.com
```

works fine.  I want to stop the lockouts rather than allowing the use of the Netbios format.  Full details of what I have found are below

[image]

We are upgrading to Windows 2016 from Windows Server 2008 R2- I have general user accounts on both domains which I keep the passwords in sync. The domain is still at 2008R2 but the servers this is occurring on appear to be only 2016 servers.

I have

- a FQDN domain "DOM2.DOM1.com" with a Netbios name of DOM2

  - user User2  in DOM2
  - Member Server Server2 in DOM2
- a FQDN domain "DOM1.com" with a Netbios name of DOM1

  - user User1 in DOM1
  - Member Server Server1 in DOM1
- The users USER_2 and USER_1  both have the the same password
- The DNS is setup so that both domains can resolve each other without the use of Fully qualified names

  - Member servers in both domains have both DOM1.Com and DOM2.DOM1.COM in the DNS suffix search list
  - DOM1.com delegates the DOM2.DOM1.com DNS zone to the DNS servers of DOM2.
  - DOM2.DOM1.com DNS Servers forward unknown DNS queries to the DNS servers of DOM1.
    [image]

Previously I have been mapping drives by running the following on server1 logged on as User1

```
net use \\SERVER2  /user:DOM2\User2
```

and then using commands like

```
net use X: \\SERVER2\SHARE1  
net use Y: \\SERVER2\SHARE2
```

to map the drives but using the cached credentials from the first command

This used to work but now I am getting the credentials are invalid on the first command and If I repeat this multiple times my USER2 account gets locked for bad passwords

I have found that if type the following  on Server1

```
net use \\SERVER2.DOM2.DOM1.com  /user:DOM2\User2@DOM2.DOM1.com 
net use \\SERVER2  /user:DOM2\User2@DOM2.DOM1.com
```

both these formats works 
The DNS Suffix search list allows the resolution of the SERVER2 name from a DOM1.COM server

My aim is - since the account and password are correct and despite this I am getting locked out - is there some method I could use to prevent this lockout - Complete denial of using the Netbios names format is fine.  If I could get Powershell scripts which allow the setup of the cached credentials However when I looked at the Power-shell map drives functions but it does not seem to have the ability to map to \SERVER2.DOM2.DOM1.com - It requires you to map to an explicit share